# How to fetch Birt parameter values in GridEventHandler class?

Tags: java, birt

I am setting paramets map like this in my generateReport() method. But I am not able to retrieve this in EventHandler class.

```
IRunAndRenderTask task =
engine.createRunAndRenderTask(reportRunnable);
Map< String, Object > birtParams = ...;
task.setParameterValues( birtParams );
```

What I am trying to retrieve:

```
reportContext.getAppContext().get(KEY_NAME);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh.. It wa simple.. Got the way to fetch parameter value. Here it is-

```
reportContext.getParameterValue(KEY_NAME);
```